# Removing duplicates in sql using the lowest number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question regarding SQL.

Let's say I have a table that have only 2 columns and it looks like this:

```
col1    col2
--------------
12345   200000
12345   435000
200000  12345
200000  435000
435000  12345
435000  200000
600     1200
600     900
900     600
900     1200
1200    600
1200    900
```

How do I make it so that the result looks like this?

```
col1    col2
---------------
12345   200000
12345   435000
600     900
600     1200
```

The logic behind this is that I want to get the lowest number as the main "key".
As 12345 matches to 200000 and 435000, and since 12345 is the lowest, it becomes the main key to match to the other 2 numbers.

You can think of it as ID numbers.
(12345 = 200000 = 435000) & (600 = 900 = 1200). Since 12345 is the lowest out of the first group and 600 is the lowest out of the second group, i would only want to display 12345 and 600.

I have tried:

```
select col1, col2
from table_name
where col1<col2
```

but I had extra rows:

```
Extra row 1: 200000,435000. 
Extra row 2: 900, 1200.
```

Comment: Why are _both_ `600` and `12345` in your output, given that the former is the lowest number?

Comment: I think OP meant to select the records with `col1` lower than `col2`. It is a simple `WHERE` query. See if you can cook something together and let us know the results

Comment: @RisingSun Go ahead and post that.  It looks right at least empirically.

Comment: Hi, yes i did try to use a where condition. But it gave me extra rows. Extra row 1: 200000,435000. Extra row 2: 900, 1200.

Comment: @P.Salmon please see my edit. Do not be so quick to close as I have already shared the expected output.

Comment: Why aren't `(200000,435000)` and `(900, 1200)` in your expected output. The logic needs more clarification.

Comment: @rad Huh? They aren't in my expected output because i do not want them in my expected output. Like I mentioned in my post:
You can think of it as ID numbers. (12345 = 200000 = 435000) & (600 = 900 = 1200). Since 12345 is the lowest out of the first group and 600 is the lowest out of the second group, i would only want to display 12345 and 600.

Comment: What do you mean by first group and second group? How is the grouping performed?

Comment: @rad thanks for trying to help/understanding my question. Someone has managed to understand my question and has kindly provided the solutions. Please refer below if you are still unsure. Thanks!

Comment: The key point is not explained clearly enough: `col1, col2` is an *unordered pair*  of data: so, for example  `10, 15` and `15, 10` are equivalent.

Comment: Also, @JaneDoe please post sample data as well formatted text and not in the form of images. I had to manually write down your sample data in order to test my query before posting it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT IF(col1 < col2, col1, col2) col1,
       IF(col1 >= col2, col1, col2) col2
FROM mytable
GROUP BY IF(col1 < col2, col1, col2),
         IF(col1 >= col2, col1, col2)
```

to get:

```
col1    col2
---------------
600     900
600     1200
900     1200
12345   200000
12345   435000
200000  435000
```

So, using the above as a derived table:

```
SELECT MIN(col1) col1,
       col2
FROM (       
   SELECT IF(col1 < col2, col1, col2) col1,
           IF(col1 >= col2, col1, col2) col2
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY IF(col1 < col2, col1, col2),
            IF(col1 >= col2, col1, col2)
) AS t
GROUP BY col2
```

gives you the expected result:

```
col1    col2
---------------
600     900
600     1200
12345   200000
12345   435000
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f49a92/7)